# VTK: find diameter of bounding sphere of a mesh

Tags: visualization, vtk

I have a mesh model and am displaying it in VTK. I would like to find the diameter or radius of an enclosing sphere that tightly bounds the mesh. This is so that I can place the camera at least this distance from the model.

Thanks,
Aly

Answer (score 0):

How about a bounding box instead? http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/DataBounds . Note: this is an axis-oriented bounding box (i.e. it is specified by min/max coordinates in each of the 3 axes.